# Is it possible to disable upload of artifacts to TeamCity master?

Tags: upload, teamcity, artifacts

I have created some build configurations with snapshot and artifact dependencies (to create a build chain). The configurations are executed always on the same agent so upload of artifacts to master is not necessary.

Is that possible in TeamCity? Can I somehow avoid the upload of artifacts to master and rather pass the artifacts directly to the next build configuration in the chain?

Thanks in advance.

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to disable the upload of artifacts to TeamCity, as build agents are allowed to come and go.
But since v. 8.1, TeamCity build agent caches artifacts while uploading them, so they are not re-downloaded again, when next build starts.

Comment: Thanks. Have found that also in the documentation: 
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Artifact (search for 'cached in the local artifact dependencies') and 
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Free+disk+space#Freediskspace-Configuringartifactscache on how to configure it.